# Can't access JSON keys (undefined) from a JS API call

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxf0--uiX0I) from the YouTube channel `The Coding Train`, can consist on make API from JS using fetch. In particular I'm using this code:

```js
const api_url =  "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544/positions?timestamps=1436029892,1436029902&units=miles"


async function getISS(api_url) {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.latitude);
    console.log(data);
    //return data

}


getISS(api_url)
```

This codes does run, and I'm getting the response form the API but this line:

```
console.log(data.latitude);
```

Is not printing the corresponding value, while in the video tutorial it does work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The result is an array, not an object. Are you sure you have the correct URL?

Comment: console.log(data.map(i=>i.latitude));

Comment: According to the docs of the [wheretheiss.at](https://wheretheiss.at/w/developer) site, you'll get an array when you ask for the *positions* data. Try the following endpoint: `https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544`. @Phix is correct.